# Coordinates of position of first element after body

Tags: jquery

I can get the coordinates of an element if it has an id:

```
$('#div1').offset();
```

How can I get the coordinates of the first element of a webpage after the body-element, without knowing what element or class it is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you mean you want the first element inside the body element.

You can use:

```
$('body').children(':first').offset();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [first child selector](https://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/) to select the first child of the body.

```
$( "body :first-child").offset();
```

Comment: @RickHitchcock - It should actually be `body>:first-child`.

Comment: @RickHitchcock - Thanks for your original comment though. At first glance I thought it looked fine without the space.

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript for this:

```
  document.body.firstChild
```